# Inserting records to a table by looping through another column and using second table the ID as one of the fields

Tags: sql, sql-insert

What I am trying is to loop through the following records from the subquery and assign the ID from the ARINVT table as the first column value for the Inert query. The other two values will be consistently hard keyed. I think the problem is that my subquery returns all the rows from the ARINVT but I need to loop through each one of those rows one at a time when inserting rows to the FGMULTI table. I don't know how to do that although I suspect somehow, I could have a variable be assigned the ID value of the current row I am on in the loop? Just not sure how to proceed.

```
Begin

For v in (

Select
  ID
From ARINVT
Left Join ARINVT inv on inv.ID = br.ARINVT_ID
  and inv.CLASS = 'WP')

Loop

Insert Into FGMULTI (ARINVT_ID, LOC_ID, AUTO_DISPO_DEFAULT_LOC)

VALUES
((Select ID FROM ARINVT WHERE CLASS='WP'),27052, 'Y')


End Loop ;

End ;
```

The full script returns the following error:

> Begin
>
> For v in (
>
> Select   ID From ARINVT Left Join ARINVT inv on inv.ID = br.ARINVT_ID
> and inv.CLASS = 'WP')
>
> Loop
>
> Insert Into FGMULTI (ARINVT_ID, LOC_ID, AUTO_DISPO_DEFAULT_LOC)
>
> VALUES ((Select ID FROM ARINVT WHERE CLASS='WP'),27052, 'Y')
>
> End Loop ;
>
> End ;
> -- OK.  [   0.0080 sec] 0 Rows Affected
>
> -- Failed: [FireDAC][Phys][Ora] ORA-06550: line 18, column 3: PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended ORA-06550: line 13, column
> 1: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored ORA-06550: line 21, column 5:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the
> following:
>
> loop
>
> Manual SQL Statement -> Finished with 1 error(s).

The subscript returns the following error:

> Insert Into FGMULTI (ARINVT_ID, LOC_ID, AUTO_DISPO_DEFAULT_LOC)
> VALUES ((Select ID FROM ARINVT WHERE CLASS='WP'),27052, 'Y')
> -- OK.  [   0.0190 sec] 0 Rows Affected
>
> -- Failed: [FireDAC][Phys][Ora] ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
>
> Manual SQL Statement -> Finished with 1 error(s).

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are trying to do. Here is Your code (a bit structured for readability) along with comments on what is wrong. The main dilema is what your cursor should look like.

```sql
Begin
    For v in (Select ID     -- ID from first ARINVT or self joined one (aliased inv) --> I assumed the first one and put it as br.ID
              From ARINVT   -- there is no alias though you use it in Left Join's ON clause
              Left Join ARINVT inv on inv.ID = br.ARINVT_ID and inv.CLASS = 'WP')   -- ON clause should be surrounded with brackets ()
    Loop
        Insert Into FGMULTI (ARINVT_ID, LOC_ID, AUTO_DISPO_DEFAULT_LOC)
                    VALUES((Select ID FROM ARINVT WHERE CLASS='WP'),27052, 'Y') -- if you were using the cursor for loop to get ID what is this Select for
                            -- Here it looks like you need IDs where CLASS is 'WP' - is it this or like in the above cursor
                            -- The cursor would be as it is here - just - Select ID From ARINVT Where CLASS = 'WP'
    End Loop ;
End;
```

... And here is how it's supposed to be to get the job done (probably) ...

```sql
Declare
    c   CURSOR IS
            Select      br.ID
            From        ARINVT br
            Left Join   ARINVT inv on (inv.ID = br.ARINVT_ID And inv.CLASS = 'WP');
    -- OR MAYBE JUST LIKE --->  c CURSOR IS Select ID From ARINVT Where CLASS = 'WP';
    m_ID    ARINVT.ID%TYPE;
Begin
    OPEN c;
    LOOP
        FETCH  c Into m_ID;
        EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
        Insert Into FGMULTI (ARINVT_ID, LOC_ID, AUTO_DISPO_DEFAULT_LOC) 
                    VALUES(m_ID, 27052, 'Y');
    END  LOOP;
    CLOSE c;
End;
```

This way you declare the cursor and a variable to fetch the ID into and Loop through rows inserting IDs one by one...